# How can I Give queue list various name in loop in Java?

Tags: list, arraylist, queue, ascii

Do you have a way please to give the Queue list varius litters name in each time

the Code :

```
for(int y=0;y<26;y++) {
                                
Queue<Float>  ----HERE---- = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

I want to make various Names Like :

Queue  A = new LinkedList<>();

Queue  B = new LinkedList<>();

Queue  C = new LinkedList<>();

Queue  D = new LinkedList<>();

Queue  E = new LinkedList<>();

..

..

Maybe I Should use Ascii code for that?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign predefined string as a variable name.
Probably if you want to access multiple queues with a different name, you can create a Map of <String, Queue>

```
Map<String, Queue> map = new HashMap<>();
for(char ch = 65; ch <= 90; ch++)
{
    map.put(Character.toString(ch), new LinkedList());
}
```